# Python program becoming unresponsive after using Queue to update customtkinter CTkImage using opencv image feed

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, tkinter, video-capture

I'm trying to create a live video feed using a customtkinter `CTkImage` stored in a `CTkLabel` with the following code:

```
self.image_w = customtkinter.CTkImage(
            light_image=Image.open(os.path.join(Constants.RESOURCES_PATH, 'blank_img.jpg')),
            size=(600, 600))
        self.img_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.image_frame, image=self.image_w, text="")
        self.img_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=10, sticky="")
```

There is a QR_Daemon class that adds images read using OpenCV to a `Queue.queue`

```
    def main(self):
        # Initialize the camera or read a video file
        itime = time.time()
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # Change to the appropriate camera 
                                   # index or video file path
        print(time.time() - itime)

        while True:
            # Read a frame from the camera or video file
            ret, frame = cap.read()

            gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

            if not ret:
                break
            if not self.img_q.full():
                self.img_q.put(gray_frame)

            # Detect and decode QR codes in the frame
            self.read_qr_code(gray_frame)

            # Wait for 2 seconds before processing the next code
            time.sleep(0.5)

            # Close the displayed window if 'q' key is pressed
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
```

I am using this code to update the customtkinter image itsel

```
    def read_cam_img(self):
        time.sleep(25)
        print("done waiting")
        if not self.img_queue.empty():
            self.image_w.configure(light_image=Image.fromarray(self.img_queue.get()))
            self.img_label.configure(image=self.image_w, text="")
            time.sleep(2)
```

and then they are both called in:

```
    def launch_qr(self):
        qr_daemon = QRDaemon(member_list=self.member_section, img_q=self.img_queue)
        qr_daemon_thread = threading.Thread(target=qr_daemon.main)
        qr_daemon_thread.daemon = True
        qr_daemon_thread.start()

        img_update_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.read_cam_img())
        img_update_thread.daemon = True
        img_update_thread.start()
```

Based on what I've read, it seems that the `Queue.queue` should be threadsafe in Python, however, when I run the actual code, I end up with this:
[Unresponsive Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zuvaa.png)

I changed the 'while' loop in `read_cam_img` to an `if` statement (so it would only run once) and when I did that, the image did appear in the GUI (image frame). That leads me to believe that it is some kind of time complexity issue (maybe?).

I then altered the code to look like this:

```
self.image_w.configure(light_image=Image.fromarray(self.img_queue.get()))
            self.img_label.configure(image=self.image_w, text="")
            time.sleep(2)
            self.image_w.configure(light_image=Image.fromarray(self.img_queue.get()))
            self.img_label.configure(image=self.image_w, text="")
            time.sleep(2)
            self.image_w.configure(light_image=Image.fromarray(self.img_queue.get()))
            self.img_label.configure(image=self.image_w, text="")
            time.sleep(2)
            self.image_w.configure(light_image=Image.fromarray(self.img_queue.get()))
            self.img_label.configure(image=self.image_w, text="")
```

instead of the while loop and when I do this, the image updates only once (showing only the first frame in the GUI) even though there are more frames in the queue.

I've also got a link to my full program here for reference: https://github.com/StarkOdinson612/QRAttendanceV2/tree/VideoFeed

Comment: (1) In `read_cam_img` you loop continuously burning up non-productive CPU cycles if the queue is empty. Why do you do that instead of doing an unconditional call to `self.img_queue.get()` without first testing whether the queue is empty? (2) You have `if self.img_q.not_full:`.  What do you think you are accomplishing with this test? This expression will always be the equivalent of `True` when tested with an `if` statement (it's a non-None reference to a `Condition`). This is *not* how you would test for a queue not full condition;. Call the `full()` method to see if it the queue is full.

Comment: @Booboo I've updated the code based on your suggestions (which should be in the question now). But the customtkinter image is still not updating properly, do you know what could be causing this? (the queue is also not empty)

Comment: I said you should replace `if self.img_q.not_full:` with `if not self.img_q.full():`. I am not saying that this is your only problem, but what you have appears to me to be completely wrong if you are trying to test for the queue not being full.

Comment: It looks the post didn’t update properly, but that is what I’m using and that part seems to work correctly. It’s just the tainted image that isn’t

Comment: This is the first time you are mentioning a **tainted image**, whatever you mean by that. I am not that familiar with image processing. I suggest you update your post with what currently are the remaining problems with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that it becomes possible for someone, if not I, to help you. Right now the question is a bit of a mess since I am not sure it describes the problems that remain.

Comment: Sorry about that, that was another typo, I meant to sat `tkinter` image as in the image in the GUI. I've also updated my post to include more details and what I've tried as per your recommendations.

Comment: You are calling the `read_cam_img` and then using the result to attempt to start a thread in: `img_update_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.read_cam_img())`. So, `launch_qr` waits 25 seconds. You probably want ``img_update_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.read_cam_img)``

Comment: @tdelaney It seems that what you pointed out was indeed the issue and I've added an answer to the question to reflect this. Really appreciate the help by the way.

Answer (score 1):

The issue in the code only seemed to be in the thread creation for `img_update_thread` as @tdelaney pointed out in the comments. After changing it to:

```
img_update_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.read_cam_img)
```

The code works as intended and FPS can be pushed up as desired (I just have it at 20 for now)

Comment: This has been nipping python programmers forever. By default `Thread` expects you to override its `run` method in a subclass. `target=` is a shortcut that lets you run a function in the thread instead. But its easy to make mistakes like this. Because your function returned `None`, which is the default for `target=`, `Thread` assumed that you've overriden the `run` method. Many late night debug sessions would have been avoided if `threading` had used a separate factory function instead. Its an interesting lesson in overloading the roles of a class.

Comment: Yeah, and Pycharm also autocompletes to calling the function by default and doesn't show any warnings or anything so at first I just figured it was also an acceptable way to create the thread :P